# Why does media source not work with Safefilenames?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add filenames (without the full path) to the `ListBox`.

[image: Like This]

The code below is working smoothly, but when when I change `FileNames` to `SafeFileNames` (for hiding item location) it's not working anymore.

## XAML

```xml
<MediaElement x:Name="mePlayer" Margin="64,0,90,61"/>
<ListBox x:Name="listbox4" Background="Salmon" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3"/>
```

## CS

```
private void load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.DefaultExt = ".mp3";
    ofd.Filter = "All|*.*";
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ofd.FileNames.Length; i++) 
        {
            listbox4.Items.Add(ofd.FileNames[i].ToString());
            listbox4.SelectedItem = ofd.FileName;
            mePlayer.Source = new Uri(
                listbox4.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
                UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            mePlayer.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;    
        }                       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work for you. Please read the comments in the code before you proceed.

```
     private Dictionary<string, string> fileDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 

    private void load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.DefaultExt = ".mp3";
        ofd.Filter = "All|*.*";
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < ofd.FileNames.Length; i++)
            {
                var filePath = ofd.FileNames[i];
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                fileDictionary.Add(fileName, filePath);
                // not sure about this logic. You may need to reconsider what you are trying to do here.
                //Instead of doing this, create a click event for the list box and get the selected file path to be played from the dictionary.
                listbox4.Items.Add(fileName);                  
            }
        }
    }

 private void listbox4_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
 { 
    if (listbox4.SelectedItem != null) 
    { 
        var selectedFile = listbox4.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string selectedFilePath;
        fileDictionary.TryGetValue(selectedFile, out selectedFilePath);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedFilePath))
        {
            mePlayer.Source = new Uri(selectedFilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            mePlayer.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
        }
    } 
 }
```

Comment: It's working for only one loaded file.

When I write code on selection change , its not working.

I wrote this code :

`private void listbox4_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (listbox4.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                mePlayer.Source = new Uri(listbox4.SelectedItem.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                mePlayer.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
            }
        }`

Comment: That's not quite correct. See my updated answer for more samples.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I love you buddy.

Comment: You are welcome. Pls vote and accept the answer if it helped. :)

Comment: Why at the end of the item is selected when I load?

When I write this code inside load button

 `listbox4.SelectedItem = fileName;`

Comment: Because you are looping through. End of the loop you always get the last file name.

Comment: How can I get always first file name??